# How to select the minimum value in a table or the next one in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `L1_CI_PER_ADDRESS` with these columns

```
PER_ID,
SEQ_NUM,
ADDRESS_ID,
ADDRESS_TYPE_XFLG,
START_DT,
END_DT,
SEASON_START_MMDD,
SEASON_END_MMDD,
ADDRESS_PRIO_FLG,
DELIVERABLE_FLG,
VERSION,
LOAD_DATE
```

I want to select `ADDRESS_TYPE_XFLG` where the value is `MAIN-AE` if it exists or the `MAIN-EN` if the first one does not exists. Else I want to select `CORRESPOND-AE` or `CORRESPOND-AE` if `MAIN-AE` and `MAIN-EN` do not exists.

How can I do this? I am new to Oracle SQL. I want to remove the duplicates returned when I do my select.

One of the issues is that some person ID's have all four (`MAIN-AE, MAIN-EN, CORRESPOND-AE, CORRESPOND-EN`), so in this case I just want `MAIN-AE` to be returned.

I hope my question is clear.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irbve.png)

Comment: And what about the "minimum value" that appears in the question title ?

Answer (score 0):

It's top-n query. Use `row_number()`:

```
select * 
  from (
    select PER_ID, address_id, ADDRESS_TYPE_XFLG, 
           row_number() over (partition by per_id 
                                  order by case ADDRESS_TYPE_XFLG 
                                           when 'MAIN-AE'       then 1 
                                           when 'MAIN-EN'       then 2 
                                           when 'CORRESPOND-AE' then 3
                                           when 'CORRESPOND-EN' then 4
                                           end) as rn
      from L1_CI_PER_ADDRESS)
  where rn = 1
```

If person can own two addresses with the same flag then you need to add proper order after `case when section`, probably something like `, seq_num desc`.

Test:

```
with L1_CI_PER_ADDRESS(PER_ID, address_id, ADDRESS_TYPE_XFLG ) as (
    select 1,  1, 'CORRESPOND-AE' from dual union all
    select 1,  2, 'MAIN-AE'       from dual union all
    select 1,  3, 'CORRESPOND-EN' from dual union all
    select 1,  4, 'MAIN-EN'       from dual union all
    select 2,  5, 'CORRESPOND-AE' from dual union all
    select 3,  6, 'MAIN-AE'       from dual union all
    select 4,  7, 'CORRESPOND-EN' from dual union all
    select 4,  8, 'MAIN-AE'       from dual
    )
select PER_ID, address_id 
  from (
    select PER_ID, address_id, ADDRESS_TYPE_XFLG, 
           row_number() over (partition by per_id 
                                  order by case ADDRESS_TYPE_XFLG 
                                           when 'MAIN-AE'       then 1 
                                           when 'MAIN-EN'       then 2 
                                           when 'CORRESPOND-AE' then 3
                                           when 'CORRESPOND-EN' then 4
                                           end) as rn
      from L1_CI_PER_ADDRESS)
  where rn = 1
```

Output:

```
      PER_ID ADDRESS_ID ADDRESS_TYPE_XFLG
  ---------- ---------- -----------------
           1          2 MAIN-AE          
           2          5 CORRESPOND-AE    
           3          6 MAIN-AE          
           4          8 MAIN-AE
```